# Cancelling async Webservice (WCF) request doesn't cancel the query execution in sql server?

Tags: sql, web-services, execution

I am using WCF webservice in ASP.NET application. The webservice gets dataset from database using Fill method of SqlDataAdapter. I observed that it is not cancelling the query (stored procedure) execution if user stops page loading.

Please let me know if there is any settings for web application, webservice to stop the query execution which is no longer required. Also the details about the request/response flow from web page to sql server.

Thanks,

Milind

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Response.IsClientConnected` property in the webservice to check if the request is still wanted.